# Each list item to open different activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, listitem

The code has a `ListView` and clicking on a list item pops up an `AlertDialog` . The `AlertDialog` has two radio buttons "yes" and "no" and then an "ok" button .

When the users select "yes" the next `Activity` is started, if selected "no" they stay in the same `Activity`.

My problem is: no matter which list item I choose, I am taken to the same 'Next-activity' . I want to be taken to different activities depending on which list item I choose.

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
final String[] items = new String[]{"IOS", "ANDROID", "WINDOWS"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        int itemposition = position;

        String itemvalue = (String) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
        final CharSequence[] items1 = {"yes", "no"};
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("slection confirmation");

        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items1, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                selection = (String) items1[which];
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items1[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        builder.setNeutralButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (selection)
                {
                    case("yes"):
                        Intent myint=new Intent(MainActivity.this,secondpage.class);
                        myint.putExtra("act1","");
                        startActivity(myint);
                        break;
                    case("no"):
                        dialog.cancel();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create string resources for all the class names of the different activities. In your 'res/strings.xml' file, you can write

```
<string name="sFirstClass">my.package.name.MyFirstClass</string>
<string name="sSecondClass">my.package.name.MySecondClass</string>
```

Please note that it's important to use the complete path to the activities.

Then, in the 'onItemClick()' method of your `OnItemClickListener`, you define a String variable and initialize it depending on the position of the clicked list item.

```
// 'final' is important so the String will be visible 
// inside the dialog button's 'onClick()' method
final String SECONDPAGE_CLASS = getMyClass(position);
```

where 'getMyClass()' is a method to match the position and the target activity:

```
private String getMyClass(int pos)
{
    String myClass;
    switch (pos)
    {
     case 0: myClass = getString(R.string.sFirstClass);
             break;
     case 1: myClass = getString(R.string.sSecondClass);
             break;
     //...
     default: // do whatever is appropriate
    }
return myClass;
}
```

Now for your OK-button you can define the `Intent` as

```
try 
{
    Intent myint = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Class.forName(SECONDPAGE_CLASS));
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Your are hardcoding `second.class` in Intent , instead try using a dynamic variable which holds value of class based on item you clicked**

```
public static Activity ClASS_NAME;
  //set CLASS_NAME based on item position for example 
     switch (selection)
                        {
                            case("yes"):
                                Intent myint=new Intent(MainActivity.this,CLASS_NAME);
                                myint.putExtra("act1","");
                                startActivity(myint);
                                break;
                            case("no"):
                                dialog.cancel();
                                break;
                        }
```

Comment: i got the idea but I started learning Android couple of weeks ago , and I am not familiar with how to use dynamic variables . I will try to google it . thank you :)